# AngularJS second program is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am learning AngularJS by seeing in one book: "**Learning AngularJS for .NET Developers**"

One task is to write a program to count how many times the color was changed, and it will display the count when it is greater than one.

At first I have tried to write on my own, then, I have tried by comparing my code with the code in book, but I could not understand why my program is not working.

Can anybody please suggest me where I am doing wrong!

Below is my completed code written in MVC view.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Introduction</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <div>
        <label>My name:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Please enter name" /><br />
        <label>My Favorite color:</label>
        <select ng-model="color" ng-change="OnColorChanged()">
            <option value="">Please select</option>
            <option>Red</option>
            <option>Yellow</option>
            <option>Magenta</option>
        </select>
        <h3 ng-show="name">Hello! my name is {{name}}</h3>
        <h3 ng-show="color">
            My favorite color is
            <span title="{{color}}" style="background-color:{{color}}">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        </h3>
        <div ng-show="colorChangeCount > 0">The favorite color was changed {{colorChangeCount}} times.</div>
        <script>
            function ExampleController($scope) {
                $scope.colorChangeCount = 0;
                $scope.OnColorChanged = function () {
                    $scope.colorChangeCount++;
                };
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the output I am getting in chrome, but it is not the right output.

[image]

Comment: Your controller and the app are not registered, check [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) for details on how to register your controller in angular for consumption, you'll need to make a module, and register the controller in that module in order to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to register the app and controller:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Introduction</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <div>
        <label>My name:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Please enter name" /><br />
        <label>My Favorite color:</label>
        <select ng-model="color" ng-change="OnColorChanged()">
            <option value="">Please select</option>
            <option>Red</option>
            <option>Yellow</option>
            <option>Magenta</option>
        </select>
        <h3 ng-show="name">Hello! my name is {{name}}</h3>
        <h3 ng-show="color">
            My favorite color is
            <span title="{{color}}" style="background-color:{{color}}">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        </h3>
        <div ng-show="colorChangeCount > 0">The favorite color was changed {{colorChangeCount}} times.</div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.colorChangeCount = 0;
            $scope.OnColorChanged = function () {
                $scope.colorChangeCount++;
            };
        }]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually as version 1.3 you should register your controller, to use controller via window object without register them(Global controller) you should call allowGlobals() from $controllerProvider